# Crystal XI R2 Server SP5...which msi file?

Tags: .net, crystal-reports, business-objects

Since the support for BO and Crystal pretty much stinks when it comes to finding an answer I thought I'd try to post this here. We are having some issues with Crystal Reports on the server and I wanted to patch it up to SP5. I finally found a download (and even then I'm confused whether to use the SP5 or FP 5.2, so I guess I'll put SP5 on first and then try the other one.  Onto my question...When you unzip the SP5 file you end up with two .msi files (CrystalReports11_5_Net.msi and CrystalReports11_5_Net_2005.msi).

We currently have Crystal Reports XI Release 2 .Net 2005 Server installed. Looking at that I would guess it would be the _2005.msi file, but I'd still like to know the difference in the two files.

Any ideas?

Comment: https://smpdl.sap-ag.de/~sapidp/012002523100004610722009E/crxir2fp52_net_si.zip

and

https://smpdl.sap-ag.de/~sapidp/012002523100001088482009E/crxir2sp5_server_install.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've somehow got a hold of the full installer (incl SP5), but yes, the VS 2005 version is the _2005 file, while the other version is for VS.NET 2002 or 2003.  See [here](http://devlibrary.businessobjects.com/businessobjectsxir2/en/en/CrystalReports_dotNET_SDK/crsdk_net_doc/doc/crsdk_net_doc/html/crconcrystalreportsdeploymentwindowsinstallerxir2.htm) for more info.

I can't seem to find a standalone or incremental SP5 download (surprises me not), so you may need to uninstall/reinstall using the file you found.

Comment: yea, that is what I thought as well. Still having issues but that's Crystal for you.

Answer (score 0):

The FP stands for Fix Pack, very much similar to Cummulative Updates for Windows.  When updating BO, you would run the SP5 setup, and then run the FP.

Thanks,

Matt